# whitespace after css scaling

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe which shows scaled websites but after scaling, a whitespace stays, and its size is the size before scaling. I have tried to wrap it around with different div's as I've found some solutions but it's not working for me, the space is still there.

You can see it [here](http://santazsolt.hu/projects/jarvis/projects.php).

HTML

```
<div id='wrap'>    
<div id='preview_div'>
     <iframe src="../404/index.php"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#preview_div {
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height:600px;
    margin:auto;
}

iframe {
    background-color:white;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 960px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: none;

    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#wrap {
    width:700px;
    height:600px;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Transforms work like `position:relative` - elements keep their original size and position within the document flow, they're just rendered with a transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the window scrollbars, you could apply `overflow: hidden` to `#preview_div` to hide the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the iFrame the container the div () has a CSS width of 630px. Also there is a pixel with on the iFrame itself.